# Problem with InstallShield 2009

Tags: c#, installshield, installshield-2009

In InstallShield 2009

how add MSI file to "after install my mproject" Install it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is really hard to understand. What I've gathered is that you want to embed a second msi file in your installer and have that msi installed after the installation of the main msi completes. Is that correct?

If so, you could make a custom action that invokes installUtil on the msi. There may be a better way, but it's been a while since I've worked with InstallShield.